# java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Tags: java, maven, javafx, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run a JavaFX application in IntelliJ. Environment - Ubuntu 18.04. Java - 11.

But it gives me error saying :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

Whole command in the run-console :

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --module-path
> /home/mua/Software/javafx_sdk-1_3_1-b05a-linux-i586/javafx-sdk1.3/lib
> --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Djava.library.path=/home/mua/Software/javafx_sdk-1_3_1-b05a-linux-i586/javafx-sdk1.3/lib -javaagent:/home/mua/Software/ideaIU-2020.3.1/idea-IU-203.6682.168/lib/idea_rt.jar=41593:/home/mua/Software/ideaIU-2020.3.1/idea-IU-203.6682.168/bin
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/mua/Desktop/PhotoSlide/PhotoSlide/target/classes:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/16-ea+7/javafx-base-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/16-ea+7/javafx-base-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/16-ea+7/javafx-fxml-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/16-ea+7/javafx-fxml-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/16-ea+7/javafx-graphics-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/16-ea+7/javafx-graphics-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/16-ea+7/javafx-media-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/16-ea+7/javafx-media-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/16-ea+7/javafx-controls-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/16-ea+7/javafx-controls-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/16-ea+7/javafx-swing-16-ea+7.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/16-ea+7/javafx-swing-16-ea+7-linux.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/11.0.2/controlsfx-11.0.2.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-core/12.1.0/ikonli-core-12.1.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-javafx/12.1.0/ikonli-javafx-12.1.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-themify-pack/12.1.0/ikonli-themify-pack-12.1.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-fontawesome-pack/12.1.0/ikonli-fontawesome-pack-12.1.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/github/dragon66/icafe/1.1-SNAPSHOT/icafe-1.1-20190902.150913-102.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/github/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/1.4.0/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.6/imageio-core-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/common/common-lang/3.6/common-lang-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/common/common-io/3.6/common-io-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/common/common-image/3.6/common-image-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-tiff/3.6/imageio-tiff-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-psd/3.6/imageio-psd-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.6/imageio-metadata-3.6.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.0-alpha1/slf4j-simple-2.0.0-alpha1.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.0-alpha1/slf4j-api-2.0.0-alpha1.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.200/h2-1.4.200.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/ejml/ejml-simple/0.40/ejml-simple-0.40.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/ejml/ejml-core/0.40/ejml-core-0.40.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/javax/media/jai/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core/1.1.3/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core-1.1.3.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.16/lombok-1.18.16.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.12.0/jackson-databind-2.12.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.12.0/jackson-annotations-2.12.0.jar:/home/mua/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.12.0/jackson-core-2.12.0.jar
> org.photoslide.App

And I've added the VM with :

```
--module-path /home/mua/Software/javafx_sdk-1_3_1-b05a-linux-i586/javafx-sdk1.3/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

And added libraries too :

[image: java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found]

Source code : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/PhotoSlide

Java configurations :

```
>>java --version
openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
>>javac --version
javac 11.0.10
```

Comment: Try to use the JDK version matched with your OpenJFX library version. JDK 11 with OpenJFX 11.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך i'm using java11, i've added them at bottom of the question now, please check

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך That's not the issue (I'm running OpenJDK 15 + OpenJFX 11 - But I did read somewhere there was an issue when using OpenJDK 14 + OpenJFX 14).

Anyway, OP, which option did you choose from [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)? I had similar BS problems couple of days ago when I tried the "Modular from IDE" - when the solution I found wasn't satisfactory to me, I went with Maven (I see you did that), but I think it was missing something that I need (not sure), so I went with Gradle. There was a little BS there as well, but I managed to set it up properly.

Comment: **I've Java Installed** -> **export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib** then went to intellij and edited libraries and vm options.. @DoombringerBG

Comment: What are the contents of your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @DoombringerBG here is the [pom.xml](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/PhotoSlide/blob/master/PhotoSlide/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're using [Non-modular with Maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

I built one from scratch myself following the instructions provided in the link above and noticed the picture marked in yellow.

There are 2 Environment Virables that need to be set for the OpenJDK. One in your system (e.g. `./bashrc` file) and one in IntelliJ for Maven (in case you're using Java 11 or above, which you are in this case).

As per your post, I know you have the one in your system, but it doesn't mention the one in this picture, so make sure you do.

Also, notice I haven't set up any VM options!

The link above states:

> The JavaFX classes will be recognized. Notice also that Maven manages
> the required dependencies: it will add `javafx.base` and
> `javafx.graphics` that are required by `javafx.controls` and
> `javafx.fxml`, but most important, it will add the required classifier
> based on your platform, downloading the specific platform jars.

[image: OpenJDK ENV in Maven]

This is my `pom.xml` file (auto-generated by IntelliJ when making the project):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing_maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.company.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I strongly recommend looking through the link I posted. You might've missed something. If not, then definitely try and create a new testing project, follow the instructions and see if it works. If it does, compare things to your current project.

Sorry, I couldn't have been of more help. I don't really work with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA,if you want create maven project that will use javaFx library in java version after 1.8 you have to :

- choose new project -> choose as build system: Maven

[image: create new maven project]

- the pom.xmm file must have this as minimum:

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ```

  4.0.0

  ```
   <groupId>com.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>machines</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
       <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
           <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
           <version>${javafx.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
           <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
           <version>${javafx.version}</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <mainClass>
                       com.insa.projet_info.projet_ge2_2023.Main
                   </mainClass>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  ```
- Now the big famous mistake that causes javafx library missed errors is people tend to run the maven app as usual app (no maven) from Run -> Main
  **I think that in IntelliJ IDEA, Maven projects should be configured and run as "Maven Projects."**
  When you create a Maven project, IntelliJ IDEA recognizes it as such and provides various Maven-related functionalities.

To run a Maven goal, like "javafx:run," you indeed need to **access the "Maven" tab on the right**. This will open the Maven tool window on the right side of the IDE.
In the "Maven" tool window, you can **expand your project to see all the available goals under "Lifecycle" and "Plugins." To run "javafx:run," you should expand your project, go to "Plugins," and find "javafx."**

**Right-click on "javafx:run" and select "Run 'javafx:run'."** This will execute the JavaFX application with the appropriate Maven configurations.

You can also **configure shortcuts for specific Maven goals, including "javafx:run," as you mentioned. This can be done by right-clicking on the goal and choosing  second choice : "'someName[javafx:run]'."** Once created, you can use the shortcut (e.g., Shift + F10) to run it in the future.

[image]

After running "javafx:run" successfully, you should see your JavaFX application window without errors, provided that your project and configurations are set up correctly.